# Splitting up a Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, html, matomo

The recommendation of the open source web analysis software Piwik is to put the following code at the end of the pages you want to track, directly before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
    [...]
</head>
<body>
    [...]
    <!-- Piwik -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://piwik.example.com/" : "http://piwik.example.com/");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script><script type="text/javascript">
    try {
    var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", 4);
    piwikTracker.trackPageView();
    piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
    } catch( err ) {}
    </script><noscript><p><img src="http://piwik.example.com/piwik.php?idsite=4" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
    <!-- End Piwik Tracking Code -->
</body>
</html>
```

Under the following assumptions:

1. https is never used
2. we don't care that the page loads slower because the script is loaded before the DOM

is it okay to convert the above to the following:

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    [...]
    <script src="http://piwik.example.com/piwik.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    [...]
    <noscript><p><img src="http://piwik.example.com/piwik.php?idsite=4" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Custom Javascript file with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker("http://piwik.example.com/piwik.php", 4);
        piwikTracker.trackPageView();
        piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
    }
    catch(err) {
    }
}
```

Are there any differences?

Answer (score 0):

You are deferring the tracking until the page is fully loaded. Inline Javascript is executed when the browser finds it, so you'll have different number of visits depending on where you call `piwikTracker.trackPageView();`. The latter you call it, the lesser number of visits/actions will be counted.

Now, what do you consider a visit/action? If a user click on a link on your page, before the page fully loads, do you consider it a visit?